# Reorder the columns on bootstrap for large screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 and with mobile first approach the columns stack perfectly on top of each other for smaller screens

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3  ">
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 ">
  <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3  pull-left">
  <h1>3</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

But on a larger screen the columns reorder and looks something like this

[image]

The intended order needs to look like this

[image]

Ordering columns doesn't seem to work either.
Would like to know about other approaches to achieve this

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty tricky thing to achieve because its now moving into a masonry type layout rather than the standard columns and rows that bootstrap is used to. You could do something like that using the card-columns component.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

```js
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
   1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   3
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Then if you are using sass you just use this.

```css
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-between(xs, sm) 
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-between(md, xl) 
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```